# How to stub current_user method in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, cancan

I have a simple user login system:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def logged_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= begin
                        if session[:current_user_id]
                          User.find(session[:current_user_id]) rescue nil
                        end
                      end
  end
end
```

which I include in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  helper SessionsHelper
```

I am trying to test the banners controller:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Admin::BannersController do
  describe 'POST create' do
    let(:user){  create(:user_admin) }
    before do
      controller.stub(:current_user){ user }
    end

    it "create action should render new template when model is invalid" do
      Banner.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
      post :create
      response.should render_template(:new)
    end
```

:user_admin is the properly set up Factory Girl admin user.

However the test still says: **You are not authorized to access this page.**
This is from Cancan.

Did I not stub it properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  def fake_user
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, :id => 100000 + rand(100000))
    stub(controller).current_user { user }
    user
  end
```

Comment: I placed this as in the spec and called it in a before block but it still doesn't work

Comment: may be you need to set instance variable @current_user

Comment: You should use rspec sequences instead of creating ids randomly